# Reverse proxy with login for redirecting different users to different applications

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, proxy, redirection, reverse-proxy

Im trying to configure the topology you can see in this picture:

[image: The picture]

My question is, having a unique login server acting as a reverse proxy, is it posible to redirect the users to their respective server application? 
This way they will be using the same login link, but each user will be redirected to their particular application

Comment: Is there a requirement that the visible URL be identical regardless of app?

Comment: Thats the idea, to have the same url for all the users on the login page, once they are logged in, i dont mind the url they are redirected to.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use user session and onces session created it should point to same back node.

For this need to preserve host by adding below config

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Comment: Yes, but what i dont know is how to redirect to one node or another depending on the user that logged in.